# Include of the head and unique titles

Tags: php, include

I am a PHP beginner. I have seen in many tutorials that they recommend to substitute the head of the page by an include. But the title and Description should be different in each page. So, I do not understand. Is there a way to solve that? or if If want to have unique titles and descriptions I should not make an includes of the head? what is the best practice?

(I understand the utility of an includes: If I ever have to make a change I only have to go to one place.)

Sample of a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Title of the page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description of the page">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="externs/stylesheet/general.css" >
</head>
<body>

<div>Content</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The same page that puts the head in another page with an includes

```
include "head.php";
<div>Content</div>
include "footer.php";
```

Comment: "recommend to substitute the head of the page by an include" - be careful with this. Your code will be un-manageable unless your PHP files each generate a well-formed fragment - i.e. generating everything between "<head>" and "</head>" is OK, but not "<html>" to "</head>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your include files don't have to be static. You may create your `head.php` and `footer.php` and use some PHP code inside them. For example:

```
<?php
// head.php
$title = getPageTitle(); // you need to implement a way of getting a title here
?>
<!-- html code skipped -->
<title><?= $title ?></title>
```

You can do something similar in your `footer.php`. The challenge here is to define a data source from which you get the dynamic info in these files and don't ruin anything in your main code.

```
include "head.php"; // here head.php is dynamic by itself
<div>Content</div>
include "footer.php"; // and footer.php also knows what to do
```

Comment: You have a typo in your answer. You meant to say "templating engine", but you accidentally typed something unrelated called MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Yuri's suggestion to use header.php and footer.php certainly provides for a more manageable website that replicating the same styling and structural HTML across lots of different PHP files. But as per my comment elsewhere it is difficult to implement these while generating well-formed HTML. Also your code should be split up into manageable units - hence creation and consumption of '$title' will likely be in very different places (scope) within your code.

Certainly you should attempt to minimize the amount of code running in the _main context of an include file - it should only do stuff when explicitly invoked. And using a single file simplifies maintenance - e.g.

```
<?php

include('project/templater.inc.php');
$t=new template();
t->pre_output();
print "<html>\n";
$t->head("My test page");
$t->page_start();
// all entry point scripts contain something like the above, and a page_end()
// next, all the page specific stuff.... 
?>

     <div>Hello world</div>

<?php
$t->page_end();
print "</html>";
$t->clean_up();
```

Many web frameworks solve this problem by using a front controller pattern - all requests are sent to a specific script which handles all the common elements of the pages (CSS/Javascript dependencies, include paths, common HTML fragments such as navigation, validating authentication).

Personally I prefer to use dependency injection - where there is a single include file providing invokable functions/methods for generating these fragments, then call these from the scripts addressed directly by URLs:

```
<?php

include("project/stdpage.inc.php");

render_page('content_for_this_page');

function content_for_this_page()
{
   print "<div>Hello world</div>\n";
}
```

Here, including a file does nothing more than defining functions including "render_page()" when that is called, at some point, it knows it needs to incorporate some page specific content - this is defined by the callback in the argument.

Comment: I just do not understand. As I said, I am a beginner